# LINQ Contains passing X.[0-9] value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to pass `" 5.[0-9]"` string to Linq `Contains()`,

```
var qry = (from b in db.X where b.XRef.Contains(" 5.[0-9]" ) 
           select b).ToList();
```

at SQL profiler the query is generated in this format

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
*FROM [dbo].[X] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[XRef] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'')',N'@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__1=N'% 5.~[0-9]%'
```

It generates an tilde `"~["` in front of left square bracket, which is not correct. The SQL I am  trying to generate is `" Select * from X where Xref like '% 5.[0-9]%'"`

Any suggestion how to solve this?